# SQL Select multiple conditions AND many times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select all the information from the Grid table where it matches multiple criteria from joining tables, ie.

```
Select * from Grid
join table1...table2...table3....table4
where (table3.product = 'product1' AND table2.rate = 2) 
AND (table3.product = 'product2' AND table2.rate = 3 AND table2.lage = 75) 
AND (table3.product = 'product3' AND table2.rate = 0.25 AND table2.lage = 75 AND table2.uage=85)
```

This is my actual select query:

```
Select * from Grid gr  
join GridToPage g2p on gr.[GridID] = g2p.[GridID] 
join Page p on p.[PageID] = g2p.[PageID] 
join PageToProduct p2p on p2p.[PageID] = p.[PageID] 
join Product pr on p2p.[ClumpCode] = pr.[ClumpCode] 
join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.[PageToProductID] = p2p.[PageToProductID] 
join ProductRates r on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] 
where 
(pr.[ClumpCode] ='CUST5G' AND r.[Rate]=2 AND r.[LowerAge] = 0 AND r.[UpperAge] = 75)
AND (pr.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST7' AND r.[Rate] = 4)
AND (pr.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST5' AND r.[LowerAge] = 75 AND r.[UpperAge] = 85)
```

There could be multiple 'AND' conditions. It would return all records that have ALL of the conditions satisfied. This query works fine with just one row of conditions but any more than one it returns no results. 
The **pr.[ClumpCode]** is a required condition, others are not and there may be additional 4 conditions for that specific [ClumpCode]. Next row of conditions apply for the other [ClumpCode] etc. 
I also tried using 'HAVING' with sum>0 for each row instead of 'WHERE(...) AND' but it was giving me some errors. 
How do I get this working when I have multiple 'AND' conditions?

------------EDIT-----------------------
Thanks for the comments, in fact the condition on [ClumpCode] should come from the Product table and not ProductRate as I had it. 
Corrected it in the queries above. It will have to be 'AND' and satisfy all the conditions to return true.

----------EDIT2------------------
Image illustrating how the search would bring back a result for the 'ML_GRID'
[image]

Comment: There's a problem with your logic.  You in effect have `r.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST5G' AND r.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST7'`, which will never be true, and therefore no rows will be returned.  Did you mean to `OR` the lines together instead?

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL to make your queries with multiple conditions.

Comment: @TobyLL I did make a mistake which I corrected. The condition on [ClumpCode] should come from a different table. So it will be pr.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST7' AND r.[Rate]=0.25

Comment: You still have a logical error, you can not `AND` these rows together, and get any results.  It is logically impossible to have a single row where the value of ClumpCode is both CUST7 and CUST5G at the same time.  I suspect that you actually want DIFFERENT rows, each one of which matches all of the conditions that you have bracketed together, in which case you need to use `OR` to join the bracketed clauses.

Comment: As per the image you have just posted, you definitely need to have `OR` between each bracketed clause.

Answer (score 2):

This is will always return false because `r` cannot have multiple `[ClumpCode]`s or `[Rate]`s or `[LowerAge]`s or `[UpperAge]`s at once.

```
(r.[ClumpCode] ='CUST5G' AND r.[Rate]=2 AND r.[LowerAge] = 0 AND r.[UpperAge] = 75)
AND ( r.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST7' AND r.[Rate] = 4)
AND ( r.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST5' AND r.[LowerAge] = 75 AND r.[UpperAge] = 85)
```

You would need to use `OR` instead of `AND` between your parenthetical conditions.

Comment: I updated my question, It will have to be 'AND' condition however the [ClumpCode] will come from a different table (pr) not r as I had it originally @mstbaum

Comment: Aida you ought to listen to @mstbaum.

Answer (score 1):

A single can't have different values for **[ClumpCode]**, you need **OR**ed conditions. This is usually done using a GROUP BY/HAVING, move the conditions into a Derived Table like this:

```
join
 ( SELECT [ProductRatesID]
   FROM ProductRates 
   where 
      (r.[ClumpCode] ='CUST5G' AND r.[Rate]=2 AND r.[LowerAge] = 0 AND r.[UpperAge] = 75)
      OR ( r.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST7' AND r.[Rate] = 4)
      OR ( r.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST5' AND r.[LowerAge] = 75 AND r.[UpperAge] = 85)
   GROUP BY [ProductRatesID]
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- the number of different conditions in WHERE
 ) as r
on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID]
```

This assumes there's only a single row per condition. Otherwise you might need to do a **COUNT(DISTINCT ???)** instead.

Comment: Aida you ought to listen to @dnoeth.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above did not solve my issue. If i used 'OR' between conditions it would return all the results that had one or more conditions supplied, where I needed only matches that satisfy all the conditions.
Ended up using INTERSECT between the queries for each of the conditions and returning only the columns for the Grid table vs selecting all. Not sure this is the most efficient way of doing it.

```
Select gr.GridID from Grid gr  
join GridToPage g2p on gr.[GridID] = g2p.[GridID] 
join Page p on p.[PageID] = g2p.[PageID] 
join PageToProduct p2p on p2p.[PageID] = p.[PageID] 
join Product pr on p2p.[ClumpCode] = pr.[ClumpCode] 
join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.[PageToProductID] = p2p.[PageToProductID] 
join ProductRates r on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] 
where 
(pr.[ClumpCode] ='CUST5G' AND r.[Rate]=2 AND r.[LowerAge] = 0 AND r.[UpperAge] = 75) --condition #1
INTERSECT
Select gr.GridID from Grid gr  
join GridToPage g2p on gr.[GridID] = g2p.[GridID] 
join Page p on p.[PageID] = g2p.[PageID] 
join PageToProduct p2p on p2p.[PageID] = p.[PageID] 
join Product pr on p2p.[ClumpCode] = pr.[ClumpCode] 
join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.[PageToProductID] = p2p.[PageToProductID] 
join ProductRates r on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] 
WHERE (pr.[ClumpCode] = 'CUST7' AND r.[Rate] = 4) --condition #2
INTERSECT
....
```

Comment: I posted an answer for you that I'd like you to think about.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your query is odd:

```
join Product pr on p2p.ClumpCode = pr.ClumpCode
join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.PageToProductID = p2p.PageToProductID
join ProductRates r on r.ProductRatesID = p2p2r.ProductRatesID
```

We all looked at your image and expected to see the data organized this way instead, following the pattern from earlier joins:

```
join Product pr on p2p.ClumpCode = pr.ClumpCode
join ProductToRate p2r on p2r.ProductID = pr.ProductID
join ProductRates r on r.RateID = p2r.RateID
```

So I suspect that the relationships between those tables is not quite what you've described or at least the impression we readers got from our own assumptions. Maybe the simplest question is why is there a `PageToProductToRate` table and not a `ProductToRate` table?

None of us would have been surprised if you said you got a `UNION` to work but you told us that you got `INTERSECT` to work for you and that only deepens the mystery. I'm really curious to see what's going on here and my gut still says something is very, very wrong.

I'm guessing that if you run the query below you'll get a lot more than 11 rows (which is the number your image shows) and a lot more columns as well. If you're willing to keep sharing I'd like to try figuring this out.

```
select *
from
    Grid gr  
    inner join GridToPage g2p on gr.GridID = g2p.GridID
    inner join Page p on p.PageID = g2p.PageID 
    inner join PageToProduct p2p on p2p.PageID = p.PageID
    inner join Product pr on p2p.ClumpCode = pr.ClumpCode
    inner join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.PageToProductID = p2p.PageToProductID
    inner join ProductRates r on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] 
where
    GridID = 'ML_GRID' /* or whatever is the appropriate value here */
```

Comment: I have posted another question on the same issue with better explanations and example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810805/sql-select-multiple-conditions-many-to-many-relationship)