# SQL SELECT multiple conditions many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am struggling to find an elegant solution to this problem. 
I have 5 tables and their relationships are described in the image. 
[image]

A page can have multiple products and each product can have many ProductRates. A Page with specific Product could have many rates as well. To get around the many to many issue there is table PageToProductToRate.

Users want to query on multiple conditions where the selection could be combination of any:

- Product1 + Rate1 + rate attribute1
- Product1 + Rate1 + rate attribute2
- Product1 + Rate2 + rate attribute2
- Product2 + Rate3 + rate attribute1   etc...

This is an example of data and WHERE condition and expected results:
[image]

And another:
[image]

The query that works for me uses INTERSECT to get the right results. I tried UNION but would get results not matching all of the conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.[PageID]
FROM [Page] P
  join PageToProduct p2p on p2p.[PageID] = P.[PageID] 
  join Product pr on p2p.[Product] = pr.[Product] 
  join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.[PageToProductID] = p2p.[PageToProductID] 
  join ProductRates r on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] 
  WHERE (PR.[Product] = 'ALMOND' AND R.CommissionType = 'PREMIUM' AND R.Rate = 0.25) 
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT P.[PageID]
FROM [Page] P
  join PageToProduct p2p on p2p.[PageID] = P.[PageID] 
  join Product pr on p2p.[Product] = pr.[Product] 
  join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.[PageToProductID] = p2p.[PageToProductID] 
  join ProductRates r on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] 
  WHERE (PR.[Product] = 'WALNUT' AND R.CommissionType = 'SERVICE FEE' AND R.Rate = 1.25)
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT P.[PageID]
FROM [Page] P
  join PageToProduct p2p on p2p.[PageID] = P.[PageID] 
  join Product pr on p2p.[Product] = pr.[Product] 
  join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.[PageToProductID] = p2p.[PageToProductID] 
  join ProductRates r on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] 
  WHERE (PR.[Product] = 'HAZELNUT' AND R.CommissionType = 'EXCESS' AND R.Rate = 1.68)
```

Is there a better way of going on around this problem? I could potentially have over a dozen of these conditions and the query with all the joins could get out of the control.

Comment: Are you trying to select pages that dont have selected products?

Comment: are you using parameters to filter the data?  if so what do they look like

Comment: I think instead of `() AND () AND ()`, you need `() OR () OR ()`.

Comment: @tshoemake No. I am trying to get a list of pages that have a selected product(s) and rate(s) combo

Comment: @user1221684 I am not using any parameters or filtering the data. I am going to use this query inside MVC project (.NET, c#) to get results and display on the page.

Comment: @TabAlleman I tried with OR instead of Intersect and I get results that match one or more conditions where I need result to match all of the conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p2p.PageID
FROM
    PageToProduct as p2p
    inner join Product as pr
        on p2p.Product = pr.Product
    inner join PageToProductToRate as p2p2r
        on p2p2r.PageToProductID = p2p.PageToProductID
    inner join ProductRates as r
        on r.ProductRatesID = p2p2r.ProductRatesID 
WHERE
          (pr.Product = 'ALMOND' AND r.CommissionType = 'PREMIUM' AND r.Rate = 0.25) 
      OR  (pr.Product = 'WALNUT' AND r.CommissionType = 'SERVICE FEE' AND r.Rate = 1.25)
      OR  (pr.Product = 'HAZELNUT' AND r.CommissionType = 'EXCESS' AND r.Rate = 1.68)
GROUP BY p2p.PageID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3; /* requires all three are present, as long as no rows are duplicate */
```

Comment: this was simple and efficient, worked in every instance i tested. Much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

My best guess.

```
WITH products AS 
(
    SELECT  [Product],
            [ProductRatesID]
    FROM    Product p
            JOIN ProductRates pr ON p.[Product] = pr.[Product]
    WHERE   (p.[Product] = 'ALMOND' AND pr.CommissionType = 'PREMIUM' AND pr.Rate = 0.25)
            OR (p.[Product] = 'WALNUT' AND pr.CommissionType = 'SERVICE FEE' AND pr.Rate = 1.25)
            OR (p.[Product] = 'HAZELNUT' AND pr.CommissionType = 'EXCESS' AND pr.Rate = 1.68)
)
SELECT  P.[PageID]
FROM    [Page] P
        JOIN (
            SELECT  p2p.[PageID], COUNT(*) as ProductCount
            FROM    products pr
                    JOIN PageToProduct p2p ON p2p.[Product] = pr.[Product]
                    JOIN PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.[PageToProductID] = p2p.[PageToProductID] 
            WHERE   p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] = pr.[ProductRatesID]
            GROUP BY p2p.[PageID]
        ) sq ON sq.[PageID] = p.[PageID]
WHERE   sq.ProductCount = @ProductFilterCount
```

You'll need to figure out how you want to handle `@ProductFilterCount`.  It can either be a count of the number filters you're using, or the number of products that actually match those filters

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82b9fe/18)

Comment: I am not sure what's the need for the product filter you're referring to? I am still trying to get this to work, it only returns results if I have one 'WHERE" condition. Why did you have count(*) in select statement? @user1221684

Comment: Look at the SQL Fiddle I created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking.. but if you want pages that have product selections then this might work, you'll have to test yourself though

edit- changed to AND because he wants all conditions met

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.[PageID]
FROM [Page] P
  join PageToProduct p2p on p2p.[PageID] = P.[PageID] 
  join Product pr on p2p.[Product] = pr.[Product] 
  join PageToProductToRate p2p2r on p2p2r.[PageToProductID] = p2p.[PageToProductID] 
  join ProductRates r on r.[ProductRatesID] = p2p2r.[ProductRatesID] 
  WHERE (PR.[Product] = 'ALMOND' AND R.CommissionType = 'PREMIUM' AND R.Rate = 0.25) 
  AND (PR.[Product] = 'WALNUT' AND R.CommissionType = 'SERVICE FEE' AND R.Rate = 1.25)
  AND (PR.[Product] = 'HAZELNUT' AND R.CommissionType = 'EXCESS' AND R.Rate = 1.68)
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax.   "EXISTS(" has to be followed by a SELECT.